# Not able to change the program number for the video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have been trying to change the program number of a particular .ts file using FFmpeg without any success. I saw the documentation and it mentions to use the -program option. But, I am not able to add the streams as I desire. Here's the program information for the stream that I possess currently:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from 'output_2_without_pgm_num.ts':
  Duration: 00:01:49.92, start: 1.400000, bitrate: 1816 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
  service_name    : Service01
  service_provider: FFmpeg
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x101](ger): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s (clean effects)
Stream #0:2[0x102](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 384 kb/s (clean effects)
Stream #0:3[0x103](ger): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
```

Now, I want to change the program number from 1 to 22. Any idea how I could do that? I have tried using -program option, but I can't add streams 2 and 3 to the newly created .ts file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps involved here. Telling ffmpeg which streams to include in the output using the `-map` option, and setting the program metadata, using the `-program` option.

```
ffmpeg -i in.ts -map 0 -c copy -program program_num=22:st=0:st=1:st=2:st=3 out.ts
```

`-map 0` tells ffmpeg to include all streams from the first input.

The `st` values tell ffmpeg which output stream indices should be included in the program.

Comment: Yes, it is working now. It seems that I swapped the order of the options provided above resulting in an error. Thank you, Gyan